builtin lsp completion not working
Using neovim 0.11 I wanted to use the built in completion feature, here's my configuration to use it when the lsp is being used:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("LspAttach", {
        group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("UserLspAttach", { clear = false }),
        callback = function(ev)
                vim.lsp.completion.enable(true, ev.data.client_id, ev.buf, { autotrigger = true })
        end
})

The function is called, I verified the argument I had, everything seems right, however when editing my buffer I don't have the completion menu popping, I need to trigger a keymap that calls vim.lsp.completion.trigger and only then it works
what am  i missing here?
